# Showing list on the same line

Tags: html, css

Tried everything, pulled the original code off w3schools and tried to edit it myself but lost at the issue. I tried putting in display:inline; and trying some of the other answers to the questions on here but to no avail.

```css
/* Div setup */

.wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.header {
  background-color:#333;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;

  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav {
  width: 100px;
  float; none;

  font-size: 12px;
}

.content {
  width:500px;
  float:left;

  font-size: 12px;
}

.side {
  width:150px;
  float:left;

  font-size: 12px;
}

.footer {
  background-color:black;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Navigation Bar Settings */

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p>The <b>Time Traveller</b> Bookstore</p>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Vault</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec justo libero, feugiat at est nec, fringilla pellentesque massa. Aenean mattis mauris quis nunc interdum tincidunt. Quisque ipsum est, pharetra aliquam dapibus vestibulum, laoreet sit amet metus. Nulla vitae lorem eros. In dictum tincidunt nisl in eleifend. Pellentesque molestie nulla et eros vestibulum, ut scelerisque enim lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin nec commodo tellus.</p> 
    <p>Fusce facilisis, ex eu tristique aliquet, nulla sapien fermentum nunc, at elementum ex leo eget metus. Nunc interdum sapien lacus, eu iaculis eros dapibus eget. Ut vitae orci varius, elementum libero nec, semper elit. Aliquam pretium rhoncus arcu, ultrices consectetur magna tempus vel. Suspendisse eu euismod lectus. Proin ut diam ornare ligula tincidunt ornare eget fermentum nisi. Pellentesque ligula augue, interdum a turpis eu, lacinia congue odio. Integer ut lorem ut nisl tincidunt tempus eu id purus. Quisque vehicula ipsum sed nulla commodo, in semper augue cursus. Aenean faucibus odio mi, congue tempus ante iaculis nec. Etiam non elit at sem blandit rhoncus ut non tellus. Donec condimentum augue non nulla vestibulum, sit amet interdum quam fringilla. Maecenas scelerisque aliquam purus, at ultricies odio.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="side">
    <p>Advert</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is currently outputting vertically.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `nav ul { display: flex }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `width: 100px` on `.nav` and set `display: inline-block` on `.nav li`

```css
/* Div setup */

.wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.header {
  background-color:#333;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;

  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav {
  /*width: 100px;*/      /* 1 */
  float: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block; /* 2 */
}

.content {
  width:500px;
  float:left;

  font-size: 12px;
}

.side {
  width:150px;
  float:left;

  font-size: 12px;
}

.footer {
  background-color:black;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Navigation Bar Settings */

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p>The <b>Time Traveller</b> Bookstore</p>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Vault</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec justo libero, feugiat at est nec, fringilla pellentesque massa. Aenean mattis mauris quis nunc interdum tincidunt. Quisque ipsum est, pharetra aliquam dapibus vestibulum, laoreet sit amet metus. Nulla vitae lorem eros. In dictum tincidunt nisl in eleifend. Pellentesque molestie nulla et eros vestibulum, ut scelerisque enim lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin nec commodo tellus.</p> 
    <p>Fusce facilisis, ex eu tristique aliquet, nulla sapien fermentum nunc, at elementum ex leo eget metus. Nunc interdum sapien lacus, eu iaculis eros dapibus eget. Ut vitae orci varius, elementum libero nec, semper elit. Aliquam pretium rhoncus arcu, ultrices consectetur magna tempus vel. Suspendisse eu euismod lectus. Proin ut diam ornare ligula tincidunt ornare eget fermentum nisi. Pellentesque ligula augue, interdum a turpis eu, lacinia congue odio. Integer ut lorem ut nisl tincidunt tempus eu id purus. Quisque vehicula ipsum sed nulla commodo, in semper augue cursus. Aenean faucibus odio mi, congue tempus ante iaculis nec. Etiam non elit at sem blandit rhoncus ut non tellus. Donec condimentum augue non nulla vestibulum, sit amet interdum quam fringilla. Maecenas scelerisque aliquam purus, at ultricies odio.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="side">
    <p>Advert</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Life saver, thanks for all patience received.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;                    /* simply set to inline-block */
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The Vault</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Order</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Report</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it outputted in this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/8dbe9946444e4d08acedd4bb69db1594.png

Comment: @JoeZalewski have you clicked "Run Code Snippet" in my answer?

Comment: Yep, you're correct, but it's not working for me at all

Comment: @JoeZalewski as you can see I just used the code you provided.

Comment: Which makes it even more annoying as it works in your answer but not when I put it into my code, something else couldn't be causing it to break would it?

Comment: Edit your question, and put the complete code in the snippet - both the HTML and the CSS. And by that, I mean the complete HTML-including the `<DOCTYPE>`-declaration, and so on.